# How to pass ids and names to d3 from rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, d3.js, hashmap, legend

As with any rationalized database, the IDs, names and data are stored in separate tables. The current script (below) shows the IDs in the legend but I would like to pass in and show the names. The question is how to combine data from two tables (one with names, one with IDs) so I can pass them to a d3 chart to show the data and the names in the legend and/labels. I suspect that there needs to be a hash in the controller but I'm not sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Model**

```
class MacroSeries < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :macro_values
end

class MacroValue < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :macro_series
end
```

**Tables**

- macro_series

  - id
  - series_name
- macro_values

  - id
  - macro_series_id
  - date
  - value

**Controller**

```
@income_equality1 = MacroSeries.where(series_code: ['WFRBSTP1300', 'WFRBSB50215'])
@mv1 = MacroValue.where(macro_series_id: @income_equality1, geography_id: @geography_id)
```

**View**

`<%= render 'macro_values/macro_values_chart', chart_num: 1, chart_data1: @mv1, chart_type: 'area_stacked', x_value: 'date', y_value: 'value', cat1: 'macro_series_id' %>`

**D3 Chart**

```
    // INPUT
    // Data
    // Assign the json data to a variable
    // Number of records
    var last = <%= last %>;
    var data = <%= raw(chart_data1.last(last).to_json) %>;

    var x_value = <%= raw(x_value.to_json) %>;
    var date_format = <%= raw(date_format.to_json) %>;
    var x_label = <%= raw(x_label.to_json) %>;
    var x_format = <%= raw(x_format.to_json) %>;

    var y_value = <%= raw(y_value.to_json) %>;
    var y_label = <%= raw(y_label.to_json) %>;
    var y_format = <%= raw(y_format.to_json) %>;

    var z_value = <%= raw(z_value.to_json) %>; 
    var cat1 = <%= raw(cat1.to_json) %>;
    var cat2 = <%= raw(cat2.to_json) %>;
    
    var chart_num = <%= raw(chart_num.to_json) %>;
    var chart_type = <%= raw(chart_type.to_json) %>;
    var color = <%= raw(color.to_json) %>;
    var legend_names = <%= raw(legend.to_json) %>;

    // Chart specifics
    // Colors
    var series_colors = ["#af3700", "#eb8f00", "#006000", "#005490", "#660066", "#600000"];
    //var colors = d3.schemeTableau10; // array of colors for z

    // Dimensions and margins
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 100, left: 40},
                width = <%= width %>,
                height = <%= height %>,
                xRange = [margin.left, width - margin.right],  // [left, right]
                yRange = [height - margin.bottom, margin.top]; // [bottom, top]
      
    // Append the SVG object to the page
    var svg = d3.select("#<%= 'chart_'+raw(chart_type)+raw(chart_data1.last.id) %>")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
                .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;")
                .style("-webkit-tap-highlight-color", "transparent")
                .on("touchstart", event => event.preventDefault());// add event listener

    // Determine the series that need to be stacked
    var series = d3.stack()
                    .keys(d3.union(data.map(d => d[cat1])))                                     // distinct series keys, in input order
                    .value(([, D], key) => D.get(key)[y_value])                                 // get value for each series key and stack
                    (d3.index(data, d => d3.timeParse(date_format)(d[x_value]), d => d[cat1])); // group by stack then series key

    // Prepare the scales for positional and color encodings
    var x = d3.scaleUtc()
                .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d3.timeParse(date_format)(d[x_value])))
                .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(series, d => d3.max(d, d => d[1]))])
                .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]).nice();

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                    .domain(series.map(d => d.key))
                    .range(series_colors);

    // Construct an area shape
    var area = d3.area()
                    .x(d => x(d.data[0]))
                    .y0(d => y(d[0]))
                    .y1(d => y(d[1]));

    // Add the y-axis, remove the domain line, add grid lines and a label
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(height / 80))
        .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
        .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick line").clone()
            .attr("x2", width - margin.left - margin.right)
            .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1))
        .call(g => g.append("text")
            .attr("x", -margin.left)
            .attr("y", margin.top)
            .attr("fill", "currentColor")
            .attr("text-anchor", "start")
            .text(y_label));

    // Append the x axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0));

    // Append a path for each series
    svg.append("g")
        .selectAll()
        .data(series)
        .join("path")
        .attr("fill", d => color(d.key))
        .attr("d", area)
        .append("title")
        .text(d => d.key);

    // HIGHLIGHT GROUP

    // What to do when one group is hovered
    var highlight = function(event, d) {
                // reduce opacity of all groups
                d3.selectAll(".myArea").style("opacity", .1)
                // expect the one that is hovered
                d3.select("."+d).style("opacity", 1)
    }

    // And when it is not hovered anymore
    var noHighlight = function(event, d) {
        d3.selectAll(".myArea").style("opacity", 1)
    }

    // LEGEND

    var legendHolder = svg.append('g')
                            // translate the holder to the right side of the graph
                            //.attr('transform', "translate(" + (margin.left) + ",0)");
                            .attr("transform", `translate(10,${height - margin.bottom + 30})`)

    var legend = legendHolder.selectAll(".legend")
                             .data(series)
                             .enter().append("g")
                             .attr("class", "legend")
                             .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

    var size = 18
    legend.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 10)
            .attr("width", size)
            .attr("height", size)
            .style("fill", d => color(d.key))
            .on("mouseover", highlight)
            .on("mouseleave", noHighlight);

    legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", margin.left)
            .attr("y", size / 2)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("fill", d => color(d.key))
            .text(function(d, i) { return series[i].key; })
            .on("mouseover", highlight)
            .on("mouseleave", noHighlight);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you want to know how to pass data into d3 (d3 question) or how to get data out of your controller to pass to d3 (rails question).. or both?

Comment: @kwerle I am able to pass data from the macros_values table/model and chart those data. However, the names associated with the macros_series_id in that table are in the macro_series table. How do I pull in the names from macro_series table and pass those together with the data to be charted in order to show names, rather than IDs, in the labels and legend? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to join the two tables in the controller, either using

1. SQL

```
    MacroValue
      .joins("INNER JOIN macro_series ON macro_values.macro_series_id = macro_series.id")
      .where(:macro_values => {:macro_series_id => @unemployment)
      .select( 'date', 'value', 'series_name')
```

2. Rails functions .joins or .includes

```
    MacroValue
       .joins(:macro_series)
       .where(macro_series_id: @unemployment)
       .select( 'date', 'value', 'series_name' )
```

Then just reference the fields in your select statement in D3.

These posts were helpful:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/active_record_querying.html
- [Complex JOIN with ActiveRecord and Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592875/complex-join-with-activerecord-and-rails-3)